# Amount of P-smooth numbers inside a given interval

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

**Edit:**

> I found a proof by P. Erdös in "A theorem of Sylvester and Schur".

#### Any suggestion to prove one of this problems?

***The following problems are equivalent:***

1. Prove that for all naturals $n, m : 1 \le n \le m$ then exists a prime $p > n$ such that:
   $$p \, |\,\prod_{k = 1}^{n}(m+k)$$
2. Prove that for all naturals $n, m : 1 \le n \le m$ then:
   $$ \sum_{p\,\text{prime}}\left\lfloor \binom{n + m}{m} \frac{n!}{p} \right\rfloor - \left\lfloor \frac{n!}{p} \right\rfloor > 0 $$
3. Prove that for all naturals $n, m : 1 \le n \le m$ then:
   $$ \omega\left(\prod_{k = 1}^{n}(m+k)\right) > \pi(n) $$

   where $\omega$ is the [Prime omega function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_omega_function) and $\pi$ is the [Prime counting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function).

   > By [Bertrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand's_postulate), for $m = n,\ n+1,\ n+2,\ n + 3$ this is true.
4. Let $\Psi(x,y)$ the number of [y-smooth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_number) numbers less than or equal to x.

   Prove that for all naturals $n, m : 1 < n \le m$ then:
   $$\Psi(m + n, n) - \Psi(m, n) < n$$

   > As a corollary of the [Størmer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St%C3%B8rmer%27s_theorem) exists a natural $M_n$ such that for all $m \ge M_n$ this is true.

**Remark:** I don't know if this is true or not, just saw the first one on internet.

**Any idea? Is a conjecture writted in another way or something?**

Comment: Hi. Some context could be interesting.Isn't it false for $n=0$ ? And if this case is excluded, then all you have to prove is that for some $p$, the int parts of both terms are different (the term on the left is clearly greater than the term on the right).

Comment: My mistake. Now i edited with more information.